# Filtering dataset by checking multiple identifier given in one cell belonging to same group given in another dataframe

Tags: r, function, filtering, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with multiple identifier per cell separated by semicolons given in column "ids":

```
df <- data.frame(
    "proteins" = c("protA; protB; protC; protD", "protE; protF; protG; protH", "protI; protJ; protK; protL"),
    "sample1" = c(1,3,2), "sample2" = c(2,6,4), "sample3" = c(7,2,3), "sample4" = c(4,4,6), "sample5" = c(2,6,7))
```

I want to check, if all identifier belongs to the same group given in another dataframe:

```
group <- data.frame(
    "proteins" = paste0("prot", LETTERS[seq(1, 12)]),
    "group" = c(rep("iso1", 4), "iso2", "iso3", "iso2", "iso2", rep("iso4", 4)))
```

I would use a function and apply to the first column of df:

```
testid <- function(x) {
    ids.tmp <- str_split(x, ";") %>% unlist
    test <- group %>% dplyr::filter(ids %in% ids.tmp) %>% pull(group) %>% unique %>% length == 1
    return(test)
}
df %>% dplyr::filter(testid(ids))
```

Applying the function does not work this way. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: your separator between protA, protB , ... is sometimes `;`, and sometimes `,`. It this correct?

Comment: Sorry for this typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can separate the data into `separate_rows` using separator as either comma or semi-colon (`,;`), you can join this expanded dataset with `group` data on `proteins` column. For each `row`, we can count the `unique` values of group and assign `TRUE` if it is 1 or `FALSE` otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(proteins, sep = "[;,]\\s*") %>%
  left_join(group, by=  'proteins') %>%
  group_by(row, across(starts_with('sample'))) %>%
  summarise(same_group = n_distinct(group) == 1, 
            proteins = toString(proteins)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row)


#  sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 same_group proteins                  
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>      <chr>                     
#1       1       2       7       4       2 TRUE       protA, protB, protC, protD
#2       3       6       2       4       6 FALSE      protE, protF, protG, protH
#3       2       4       3       6       7 TRUE       protI, protJ, protK, protL
```

---

Using base R :

```
df$same_group <- sapply(strsplit(df$proteins, '[;,]\\s*'), function(x) 
               length(unique(group$group[group$proteins %in% x]))) == 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The tidyverse apprioach works perfectly! The base R approach does not detekt if there are proteins with multiples isos (I did not metion that this could happen).

Comment: It seems to give the same output for the data you have shared.

Answer (score 0):

here is a data.table approach

```
library( data.table )
#make it data.tables
setDT(df);setDT(group)
#preteins
L1 <- transpose( lapply( tstrsplit( df$proteins, ";" ), trimws ) )
#proteins by group
L2 <- group[, .(.(proteins)), by = group]$V1
#solution
df[, allingroup := lapply( L1, function(x) 
  any( as.logical( lapply( L2, function(y) 
    all( x %in% y ) ) ) ) ) ][]

#                      proteins sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 allingroup
# 1: protA; protB; protC; protD       1       2       7       4       2       TRUE
# 2: protE; protF; protG; protH       3       6       2       4       6      FALSE
# 3: protI; protJ; protK; protL       2       4       3       6       7       TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be an approach where you add the group to all your proteins:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
#Separate
df %>%separate(proteins,into = paste0('V',1:4),sep = '; ') %>%
  mutate(id=row_number()) -> df2
#Melt data
Meltdata <- melt(df2,id.vars=c('id',paste0('sample',1:5)))
#Merge data and check proteins, adding group
Merged <- merge(Meltdata,group,by.x='value',by.y='proteins',all.x=T)
```

Which produces next. In case a protein is not present you will get `NA` in `group`:

```
   value id sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 variable group
1  protA  1       1       2       7       4       2       V1  iso1
2  protB  1       1       2       7       4       2       V2  iso1
3  protC  1       1       2       7       4       2       V3  iso1
4  protD  1       1       2       7       4       2       V4  iso1
5  protE  2       3       6       2       4       6       V1  iso2
6  protF  2       3       6       2       4       6       V2  iso3
7  protG  2       3       6       2       4       6       V3  iso2
8  protH  2       3       6       2       4       6       V4  iso2
9  protI  3       2       4       3       6       7       V1  iso4
10 protJ  3       2       4       3       6       7       V2  iso4
11 protK  3       2       4       3       6       7       V3  iso4
12 protL  3       2       4       3       6       7       V4  iso4
```